# Show that $f$ is the zero function if$f''(x)+f(x)=0$ and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $f''(x)+f(x)=0$ for all x, and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$. 
Note: we know $f^{(n)}$ (i.e. nth derivative of $f$) is continuous for all n. 
Note: $f$ can be complex. 
Note: I want to use this to prove Euler's formula $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$.
I started with $P=\frac{df}{dx}$, then $f''(x)=P\frac{dP}{df}$. Get $P\frac{dP}{df}+f=0$ and integrate at both sides, so that $P^2+f^2=0$. And we can get $P=\pm i f \Rightarrow \frac{df}{dx}=\pm if \Rightarrow \frac{1}{f}df=\pm i dx \Rightarrow \ln f=\pm ix+C$, and I stuck here.
Is the steps above are right or there's another way of prove?

Comment: The solution to your system is the zero function.  If you want to get something else, you need either $f(0)$ to be nonzero or you need $f'(0)$ to be nonzero.

Comment: @EricTowers It would seem to me to be a question about the uniqueness of a solution to the initial value problem.  That's not a trivial theorem.

Comment: $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$? $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f''+f=0$$
$$\color {red}{2f'}f''+\color{red}{2f'}f=0$$
$$(f'^2)'+(f^2)'=0$$
After integration:
$$f'^2+f^2=C$$
$$C=f'^2(0)+f^2(0)=0$$
$$f'^2+f^2=0$$
$$(f'+if)(f'-if)=0$$
Then we have :
$$f'\pm if=0$$
$$(fe^{\pm ix})'=0$$
Integrate:
$$f(x)=Ce^{\pm ix}$$
Since $f(0)=0  \implies C=0$:
$$\implies f(x)=0 \;\;\forall \; x$$

Comment: Amazing! That $e^{\pm ix}(f' \pm if)=(fe^{\pm ix})'$ is the key!

Comment: Yes integrating factor is easier here ..@Derican

Answer (score 7):

[addendum based on the comments]
If complex-valued $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ satisfies $f''+f=0$, then its real and imaginary parts also satisfy that differential equation.  Therefore it suffices to consider real-valued $f$.

[original post]
SupposeLet $g(x) = f(x)^2 + f'(x)^2$.  From $f''+f=0$ we get ...
$$
g' = (f^2+f'^2)' = 2f f'+2f' f'' = 2f f' + 2f' (-f) = 0
$$
so $g$ is a constant.  From $f(0)=0, f'(0)=0$ we get $g(0) = 0$.  Conclusion: $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$, that is $f(x)^2+f'(x)^2 = 0$ so $f(x)=0$ and $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$.

---

To prove: $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$.  Take $f(x) := e^{ix} - \cos x - i\sin x$.  Prove $f''+f=0$ and $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$.  Done.

Comment: We'd need to deal somehow with OP's request that $f$ be allowed to be complex (in which case your last step either needs more explanation or merely doesn't follow), but without knowing the domain, I'm not sure if the problem is well-posed...

Comment: Since $f(x)$ is complex, to draw the conclusion that $f(x) = 0$ one needs to use the complex absolute value, i.e., $g(x) = \lvert f(x) \rvert^2 + \lvert f'(x) \rvert^2$.

Comment: Th real and imaginary parts of $f$ satisfy the same DE wit the same intial conditions, so we may suppose $f$ real, w.l.o.g.

Comment: Yes that $f$ can be complex is the problem... and I think from $\ln f=\pm ix+C$, let $x=0$ and I get $C=-\infty$, so $f=e^{\pm ix - \infty}=0$. But it seems to be something not well-defined...